# Simple XML Serialization 3rd Party Library

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to speed up my XML parsing and I've stumbled upon [Simple XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) which looks pretty good, but I have two questions which I was wondering if anybody could help me with:

1. Does anyone have any performance figures of Simple over the built in SAXParser on an Android device? (or just in general if not on a handset)
2. Does anyone know if Simple includes support for streamed files?  Unfortunately the application I'm working on sometimes needs large XML files, and there's no room for alternatives and I can't for the life of me find any reference to streaming on the [website](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests I found that the built in SAXParser is much faster than anything else I could find.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).